# Possible values of a sum of cubes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

If $x_i$ be a sequence of integers such that $x_i\in [-1,2]$ where $i=1,2, \dots,n$. If it is given that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 =99$$
and
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i =19,$$

find min and max value of $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3$.

Also, for the max possible value of $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^3$, what is the no of $2$'s the sequence must have?

Comment: What is a MCQ ?

Comment: multiple choice question

Comment: Here are the choices-
min values - 18, 21, 19, 13
max values - 133, 121, 143, 165
number of 2's - 18, 19, 20, 21

Comment: You should not cube the sum, but rather sum the cube of the variables.

Comment: @jvdhooft Yeah no, I get that. This was just an approach. You can see that I actually separated the sum of cubes and simplified it.

Comment: @DevAggarwal:  if it is a multiple choice question, you should say that and present the choices in your original question.  Often it is easier to find a multiple choice answer than solve the problem from scratch.

Comment: @RossMillikan I want to know why my answer is incorrect, can you please see and tell?

Comment: Going from the first line to the second is not correct.  You only get one term $x_1x_2^2$ on the right, but the left has $3x_1x^2$  I don't think this is a productive approach.

Comment: okay. saw my mistake. Thanks!  I would never use such a barbaric solution but i missed the integer values part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us call $n_{-1}$, $n_1$ and $n_2$ the number of times -1, 1 and 2 appear. Note that it does not matter how many times 0 appears, because this does not add to the result of any summation. We know the following:

$$-n_{-1} + n_1 + 2 n_2 = 19 \tag{1}$$
$$n_{-1} + n_1 + 4 n_2 = 99 \tag{2}$$

Subtracting (1) from (2), we get:

$$2 n_{-1} + 2 n_2 = 80 \iff n_2 = 40 - n_{-1}$$

Using this in (2), we get:

$$n_{-1} + n_1 + 160 - 4 n_1 = 99 \iff n_1 = 3 n_{-1} - 61$$

Since $n_1$ and $n_2$ must both be positive, $n_{-1}$ is at most 40, and at least 21. In the former case we have $n_{-1} = 40, n_1 = 59$ and $n_2 = 0$, so we obtain a minimum value of:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3 = -40 + 59 + 8 \cdot 0 = 19 $$

In the latter case we have $n_{-1} = 21, n_1 = 2$ and $n_2 = 19$, so we obtain a maximum value of:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3 = -21 + 2 + 8 \cdot 19 = 133 $$

The number of 2's in the latter case equals 19.

Comment: i missed the part where it said integer values. Can you check my solution?